# Does snow ruin lightsabers?

Tags: plot-explanation, star-wars, the-force-awakens

During the battle between Kylo Ren and Rey in *Star Wars: The Force Awakens*, Rey directs Kylo Ren's lightsaber into the snow and dirt while they are grappling.  Here is the moment in the scene:

It looks like a tactical move by Rey, and Kylo Ren seems very concerned. Does snow and/or dirt deplete a lightsaber? That would be surprising since they have been slicing through thick tree trunks.

Comment: It just looks to me that they're grappling.  He's looking to me like he's just engaged in a physical confrontation with someone that has a tool that could slice through him if he makes a mistake.  I think I'd be looking concerned if I were him too.

Comment: I presumed the look of concern was because the saber was melting the snow and causing steam to billow up into his face, combined with the fact he realised he was actually losing...

Comment: No.  The blade is light/plasma, so it kicks snow's butt without consequence.  Kylo is grunting because he is in a fight to the death, Rey is forcing his arm down, he is trying to force it back up, and more generally, he's a trained Force user who was taught by the only Jedi in the galaxy, but he's getting his butt kicked by an untrained girl who has all of 30 seconds' experience in using a lightsaber.

Comment: No. Light Sabers can be used in the ocean, so a little snow or dirt won't affect it.

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how his lightsaber was constructed. This is from Legends but Kit Fisto used a [Bifurcating cyclical-ignition pulse](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Bifurcating_cyclical-ignition_pulse) which allowed him to use his lightsaber underwater. Otherwise the lightsaber would short out.

[Kylo Ren's lightsaber (canon)](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Kylo_Ren's_lightsaber) is made from:

> A single cracked Kyber crystal, barely able to contain the weapon's power, necessitated the lateral vents which diverted the extra heat produced by the crystal to either side of the hilt, and gave the weapon's red plasma blades an unstable, serrated appearance.

He could have been concerned because he was not sure how well his lightsaber would hold up against water as his was not a normal lightsaber.

On the other hand he could have just been frustrated with Rey and his inability to overpower her.